# Call a Function by alias in a Decorator

Tags: python, function, decorator

The current code I have, allows the function to call the wrapper decorator, and uses the function name in its code. However, I'm looking for a way to give the function a 'alias' in a way as an argument. Here's the current code:

```
import os, sys

# Take user input
message = input('type command: ')

# Command wrapper
ALLCOMMANDS = {}
def command(function):
    ALLCOMMANDS[function.__name__] = function
    return function 

# Commands  
@command
def foo():
    print("bar")

@command
def goo():
    print('ber')

# Run appropriate command
if message in ALLCOMMANDS:
    ALLCOMMANDS[message]()
```

For example I would want to be able to call the function by a name such as '!foo' from the user input, so maybe the argument would look like `@command(name='!foo')`, I just don't know where to go from there to use that argument in the decorator since it already has an argument.

I attempted

```
# Command wrapper
ALLCOMMANDS = {}
def command(name):
    ALLCOMMANDS[name] = name
    return name
```

but keep getting errors and I assume I am missing something

Comment: If you follow this you should be able to pass a name argument: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up a bit more on python decorators. You're getting an error with:

```
def command(name):
    ALLCOMMANDS[name] = name
    return name
```

Because of the `return name`.

Decorators are just syntactic sugar. This:

```
@command
def foo():
    print('bar')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def foo():
    print('bar')

foo = command(foo)
```

From this you can see why your original decorator works. At the end you `return function`.

Things get a little tricker when you have a decorator that takes arguments. Desugared the following:

```
@command('nickname')
def foo():
    print('bar')
```

Looks like this:

```
def foo():
    print('bar')

foo = command('nickname')(foo)
```

So, to write a decorator that takes arguments, the decorator needs to return a function that takes the function to decorate as an argument:

```
def command(nickname):
    def wrapped(f):
        ALLCOMMANDS[nickname] = f
        return f
    return wrapped
```

Also consider making `ALLCOMMANDS` an attribute on your command instead of a global (`UPPER_SNAKE` is usually reserved for constants):

```
def command(nickname):
    def wrapped(f):
        command._functions[nickname] = f
        return f
    return wrapped

command._functions = {}
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Appreciate the detailed help, and I'll implement those recommendations